# login problem and onSubmit problem in react js

Tags: reactjs, authentication, onsubmit

> I have a problem with login ( i need to check email and pass ) its only check email
> my second problem is with onSubmit in form doesn't work!

`import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import loginImg from '../../assets/images/login.svg';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

const Login = () => {

```
const [email,setEmail] = useState("");
const [password,setPassword] = useState("");
const [isLogin,setIsLogin]=useState(1);

const TOKEN_KEY = 'jwt';

const handleLogin=()=>{
    if (email === "bardia@test.com" && password === "1212"){
        setIsLogin(1);
    } else {

        setIsLogin(0)
    }
}
useEffect(()=>{
    if (isLogin === 1){
        localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, 'TestLogin');
    } else {
        localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    }
})

return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
        <form onSubmit={handleLogin} className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center align-self-center">
                <div>
                    <p className="h1">ورود</p>
                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-4 py-4 mx-auto">
                        <input className="form-control" required autoFocus type="email" onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} placeholder=" ایمیل خود را وارد کنید"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-sm-12 col-md-4 pb-4 mx-auto">
                    <input className="form-control" required type="password" onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} placeholder=" رمز عبور خود را وارد کنید"/>
                    </div>
                    <Link to="/dashboard" className="btn btn-primary" > ورود</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                <img src={loginImg}/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
);
```

};`

Comment: You would need to change a few things, 
Working example:https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-tree-ewk5q

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing well,In you code, Login component not triggered **handleLogin** method because of you don't written button type of submit. That reason not call handleLogin method in login component. so you can replace to button type submit.

syntax:

```
<input type="submit" value="Login">
```

I hope you are understand after this read.